# C# model binding to axml

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, data-binding

I'm working on a mobile android app and on the current activity, I have a C# model of events with properties such as name and id. I am trying to create axml layouts for each event in the list of events, but not sure how to do this. Unless I'm thinking of it all wrong, I was looking for something similar to Angular2's ngFor.

I'm very new to mobile development, so I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is Recycler view or adapter in android here's an exemple of implantation and how to do a recyler view on xamarin

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/

Comment: The adapter got the job done, so I didn't need to look at using a recycler view! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is not supported by default for Xamarin.Android you have two options

1. Use an existing MVVM framework such MVVMLight(http://www.mvvmlight.net) or MVVMCross (https://www.mvvmcross.com)
2. Create your own MVVM Implementation look at this example https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/Mono/tree/master/MvvmCrossXamarin

Answer (score 0):

Figured something else out. Just used a simple listView and then used a custom adapter so that I could have a multi-lined list bound to my own list of objects. It was fairly simple to setup and was easy to use.